# Conditional IF Exists Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, table-variable

I have a query to first check if something exists. If yes, insert something into a table variable. Otherwise, insert something else into the same table variable.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Main WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId)
(   
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Result 
            SELECT .... 
            FROM ... 
            WHERE...
   END
)
ELSE
   INSERT INTO @Result  
       SELECT .... 
       FROM ...  
       WHERE...
```

For some reason I keep getting the errors below complaining inside the `NOT EXISTS` condition... The ELSE part is completely fine.

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'
>   Incorrect syntax near '@Result'

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL 2016.. need more chars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parentheses don't belong around the `BEGIN`/`END`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Main WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId)   
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @Result 
        SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE...
END
ELSE . . .
```

I would also suggest that you list the columns for `@Result` for the `INSERT`.  This can prevent future problems.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Main WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId)

     BEGIN  
          INSERT INTO @Result 
          SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE...
     END

ELSE

     BEGIN
          INSERT INTO @Result 
          SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE...
     END
```

Comment: Yes removing the parentheses helps!